# Android CamcorderProfile and Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

When trying to determine supported video sizes for a device using the Camera2 API, is it OK to use [`CamcorderProfile.hasProfile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#hasProfile(int,%20int)), or is [`StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) the only way to do it?

I have a feeling that `CamcorderProfile` is not supported, because it takes an `int` for the camera ID, and Camera2 uses `String`s for IDs, but I figured there's no harm in asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera2 IDs are Strings. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList() mentions that:

"Non-removable cameras use integers starting at 0 for their identifiers, while removable cameras have a unique identifier for each individual device, even if they are the same model"

Therefore (if the OEMs are to be trusted), we can convert the camera ID to an `int`, and use that with `CamcorderProfile`

Comment: Can I cast a removable camera string id to int? Back camera id is `"0"`, front camera id is `"1"`, then removable cameras ids are `"2"`、`"3"`、`"4"`...?